# i am getting unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) error

Tags: php, syntax-error

it is very frustrating , i am getting error - >

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chat\inc\chat.func.php on line 6

in the following code and unable to find any solution. and my php version is 5.5.1 so i don't any point of 'older' version.

here is the code

```
<?php
include( 'connect.inc.php')    
    function get_msg() {
        $que = "SELECT sender , message FROM chat ";
        $run = mysqli_query($conncetion,$que)
        $messages = array();
        while ($message = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
            $messages[] = array{'sender'=>$message['sender'],'message'=>$message['message']};

        }
        return $messages;
    }    
    function send_msg($sender,$message) {
        if( !empty($sender) && !empty($message)) {
            $sender = mysql_real_escape_string($sender);
            $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);
            $query = "INSERT INTO chat VALUES('','$sender','$message') ";
            if($run = mysqli_query($con,$query)) {
                retur n true;
            } else {
                return flase;
            }
        } else {
            return flase;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: please format your code, now it's seems like incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon from the end of your include line at the top.  I saw this when I tried to edit your post and saw all of the code.  Tried formatting it for you but someone else has submitted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

@user4141363, There are couple of errors in your code.Please check below code & replace with your original code.

```
//Below Semi-column is not there in your code.

include_once( 'connect.inc.php');

// Semicolon is missing in below line so please add semicolon as below.
$run = mysqli_query($conncetion,$que);

//Array braces wrong in your code so replace this line in your code.
$messages[] = array('sender'=>$message['sender'],'message'=>$message['message']);

//Space between return true code so it's cause syntax error.
return true;

//Return false spell mistake in your code so replace below line.
return false;
```

I have edited your code in your question, please copy that code & check it your end.

Comment: Thank you editing my code.
i also came across these errors and couple of more.
i corrected all of them but that doesn't revolves my current problem. i am still getting the syntax error @line 6.

Comment: @user4141363, Add semicolon to below line => $run = mysqli_query($conncetion,$que); Let me know if it works.

Comment: I have also add above edit in your question code too. Please check now at your end. Let me know if still any issues.

Comment: @user4141363, Is Above mentioned code helps to resolve the syntax errors at your end ? Waiting for your quick answer on the same.

Comment: the missing semicolon on the include line was the trick. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @user4141363, Can you please accept my answer as correct if it helps to you to resolve your errors !